# cublasGemmEx vs. cublasDgemm on A100

Tags: cuda, cublas

I am trying to find some advantage of tensor cores by comparing the performance of cublasGemmEx  and cublasDgemm on A100. As the doc describes, cublasGemmEx on cuda11.2+A100 support FP64, and I think cublasDgemm adapts the old algorithm(CUBLAS_GEMM_DEFAULT?), cublasGemmEx should be faster than cublasDgemm. But my experiment show that both have the same performance. does cublasDgemm already adapt tensor cores? btw, for m=n=k=5440, both have about 10 TFLOPS.

Comment: Double precision GEMM is almost certainly memory bandwidth bound. If both algorithms are optimal enough to reach peak memory bandwidth, then the internal implementation probably doesn't matter

Comment: thanks for your remiding@RobertCrovella, the profiling show both have "tensor" in the kernel names: cutlass::Kernel<cutlass_80_ternsorop_d884gemm_...>.

Answer (score 2):

- For kernels such as those used by cublas, [using a profiler](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-nsight-compute-nvprof-mixed-precision-deep-learning-models/) you can identify whether tensorcore is being used, generally speaking, just from the kernel name.  For arbitrary kernels, the linked article shows a metric that can be used for this purpose, in nsight compute.
- In the case of A100, the [published data](https://www.nvidia.com/content/dam/en-zz/Solutions/Data-Center/a100/pdf/a100-80gb-datasheet-update-nvidia-us-1521051-r2-web.pdf) indicates that for non-tensorcore usage, the peak FP64 rate is 9.7TF.  If you are witnessing a throughput higher than 9.7TF (for FP64) its a safe bet that tensorcore is being used.  (Really any throughput higher than something like 90% of 9.7TF should be sufficient for this observation, as the quoted numbers are peak theoretical, not real-world-achievable).
- The CUBLAS developers want to give the library users the best experience.  I can't think of a sensible reason to use a slow path for an operation that can be done using tensorcore.  You should expect such libraries to use tensorcore when possible.
- In your case, since you are witnessing the same throughput for both operations, and that throughput exceeds 9.7TF, it's a safe bet, even without profiling, that tensorcore is being used for both.